# Adding session state in composed Actions

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there a way to add state to a session while preserving other state that has been added to it?  For a use case, consider one of the examples from http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/ScalaActionsComposition

```
 def Authenticated(f: (User, Request[AnyContent]) ⇒ Result) = {
    Action { request ⇒
      val result = for {
        id ← request.session.get("user")
        user ← User.find(id)
      } yield f(user, request).withSession(request.session + "newKey" -> "newValue")
      result getOrElse Unauthorized
    }
  }
  def index = Authenticated { (user, request) ⇒
    Ok("Hello " + user.name).withSession(request.session + "oldKey" -> "oldValue")
  }
```

I've added the two ".withSession" calls to the example.  In my tests, I haven't found a way to add "newKey" without wiping out "oldKey".

The solutions I've contemplated are all ugly.  At the moment my work-around is to keep "newKey" and associated state in my own cookie, but seems like a hassle.  Is there a way to just add it to the Play session?